# Replace Spaces With + icon

Tags: php

what is the way to replace Spaces With + icon using PHP. Suppose some text like "I Love PHP" will automatically converted like this way "I+Love+PHP" .. assuming a field has this text in a variable like> `$text = I Love PHP` so this variables text spaces will be replace with a + sign in a new variable like this> `$text_plus=I+Love+PHP` how to do it with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Str_Replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function

In your case it will be :

```
$text = "I Love PHP";
$output = str_replace(" ", "+", $text);
```

Comment: Wrong! this is technically correct answer ("how to replace..."), but completely wrong approach to the wider issue. You are dealing with url here and space it not the only character that may need encoding. You should do it right and obey the RFC rules. @Truth answer above is correct one as `urlencode()` should be used in this case.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Asker did not mention about usage. Besides, I would not assume that user wanted to URL encode ONLY. :)

Comment: @user1642787 If it worked for you, you might want to click on the tick next to my answer?

Comment: Well, seems you are right. It made my assumption on indeed, well, nothing really solid.

Comment: @KarmicDice yes this is what i was looking for. one correction a ; is missing in $output = str_.... line :)

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com appears to have simply assumed that this question was an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, but this looks like you're trying to encode the string for a URL, use `urlencode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
str_ireplace(' ','+',$text);
```